# How to remove question mark and the rest from file names?

Tags: bash, sed, find

I have grabbed a whole website template using *wget*. It created many asset files in different subdirectories where filenames contain question marks, `./fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0` for example. I need to truncate `?` and the rest from these filenames. I tried this command:

```
find . -type f -name '*\?*' -exec mv "{}" "$(echo {} | sed 's/\?.*//g')" \;
```

But it does not work; nothing is replaced/removed, it shows this error:

```
mv: './fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0' and './fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0' are the same file
```

I have these type of filenames in different directories, so I tried `find` command. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Consider [@Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67824255/5625547), this answers purely focuses on the `find` command

---

As stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67824107/how-to-replace-question-mark-and-rest-in-filenames-in-linux#comment119882001_67824107), the `sed` is called before `find` finds it files. We can work around this using `-exec bash -c` and pass the pathnames (`{}`) as argument:

```sh
find . -type f  -exec bash -c 'echo mv $0 $(sed "s/\?.*//g" <<< $0)' "{}" \;
```

If the output seems find for each file, remove the `echo` prefix to `mv` the files:

```sh
find . -type f  -exec bash -c 'mv $0 $(sed "s/\?.*//g" <<< $0)' "{}" \;
```

Small example on my local machine:

```sh
$ ls -lt
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 me wheel 0 Jun  3 17:32 'something.exe?v=23456'
-rw-r--r-- 1 me wheel 0 Jun  3 17:32 'myrandom_file?x=123'
-rw-r--r-- 1 me wheel 0 Jun  3 17:32 'fontaweietsanderssome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0'
$
$ find . -type f  -exec bash -c 'mv $0 $(sed "s/\?.*//g" <<< $0)' "{}" \;
$
$ ls -lt
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 me wheel 0 Jun  3 17:32 something.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 me wheel 0 Jun  3 17:32 myrandom_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 me wheel 0 Jun  3 17:32 fontaweietsanderssome-webfont.woff
$
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a bulletproof one.

```
find . -name '*\?*' -type f -exec sh -c '
for fp; do
  fn=${fp##*/}
  echo mv "$fp" "${fp%/*}/${fn%%\?*}"
done' sh {} +
```

The loop above isolates the name of each selected file (in the variable named `fn`) in order to be able to remove the leftmost question mark and the rest from it without breaking anything; if we did `${fp%%\?*}` instead, we couldn't process the contents of a directory with a question mark in its name. Though if we knew for sure that each file name contains only one question mark, [`${fp%\?*}`](/revisions/67824750/1) would work fine.

Remove `echo` if the output looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `rename` is not available (or you're unable to get it installed), I'd probably opt for something a bit more straight forward and easier (?) to understand/maintain.

Suppose I have the following under a directory named `question`:

```
$ ls -1 question
abc?v=4.5.0
def.txt
ghi.pdf?v=1.4.3
```

One idea using a simple `while` loop and [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

```
find . -type f -name '*\?*' |
while read -r fname
do
    echo mv "${fname}" "${fname//\?*/}"
done
```

This generates:

```
mv ./question/abc?v=4.5.0 ./question/abc
mv ./question/ghi.pdf?v=1.4.3 ./question/ghi.pdf
```

Once you're satisfied with the generated `mv` commands the `echo` can be removed in order to actually run the `mv` commands.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

A variation of [Oguz ismail's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67824750/3832970):

```sh
find . -name '*\?*' -type f -exec sh -c 'for fp; do echo mv -- "$fp" $(printf "%s" "$fp" | sed "s,?[^/]*$,,"); done' sh {} +
## or
find . -name '*\?*' -type f -exec sh -c 'for fp; do echo mv "$fp" $(echo "$fp" | sed "s,?[^/]*$,,"); done' sh {} +
```

The `find` command searches for files (`-type f`) that contain a `?` char anywhere in the file name (`-name '*\?*'`) starting from the current folder (`.`), and once the file is found the `sh` script is executed. The script is `for fp; do echo mv -- "$fp" $(printf "%s" "$fp" | sed "s,?[^/]*$,,"); done`, and it iterates over the filepaths (`fp`) found, and moves (renames) the filepaths with the same filepath without the part beginning with the first `?` char found in the file path.

The `sed "s,?[^/]*$,,"` command actually finds a `?`, then any amount of chars other than `/` till the end of string, and removes this part from the file path (so, it only removes the part of a file name, folder names can contain `?` chars).

The `--` after `mv` are necessary in case a filepath starts with a `-` char.

**NOTE**: Remove the `echo` from the above command to actually rename the files.

**Linux 18.04 tested solution with `perl-rename`**

You can use

```sh
find . -depth -type f -exec rename -n -v 's/\?.*//' {} +
```

Check the results and if they are as expected remove `-n` that is meant for a "dry" run to only check the command workings. Here, `-v` ("verbose" option) is used to print the names of files that are successfully renamed.

You can read about how to install and use this [`rename` command here](https://linuxize.com/post/rename-command-in-linux/).

Comment: Note that there lots of different tools named `rename`. This one is named `perl-rename` or `prename` on some Linux distributions.

Comment: I ran `rename -vn 's/\?.*//' $(find .)` it exits with status 4, nothing is printed, nothing changed.

Comment: `4` means: `nothing was renamed` ([man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html))

Comment: @Chitholian Try `find . -depth -type f -exec rename -n -v 's/\?.*//' {} +`

Comment: `rename --version` shows `rename from util-linux 2.36.2`, in my Fedora-34 KDE, `find . -depth -type f -exec rename -n -v 's/\?.*//' {} +` does nothing but exits `1`.

Comment: @Chitholian I tested it in Linux 18.04 and it works there.

Comment: @Chitholian I added a variation of oguz ismail's solution, with a bit shorter sh code. Also, made sure the folders can contain `?` char.